# Why is my mounted Private directory empty?

Tags: mount, encryption

I set up a Private directory following [this doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome#Encrypted_Private), and then i saw a `~/Private` dir with some readme files into it. I changed the permissions in order to be able to create files there, and i moved some files to the directory.

Upon restart, the directory is mounted, but empty. What is going on?

I am using Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: The `man` pages have much more info than that old help link, like auto mount & umount on login. And confusion often results from the similarly named Private & .private folders - fyi the encrypted folder can be renamed or moved with a little editing

Comment: Which `man` pages? Initially, i looked into Ubuntu help about private folders, but i didn't find anything

Comment: The command in the old help link you cited has a man page, `man ecryptfs-setup-private` . And just pressing TAB a few times after typing `man ecryptfs` will show you more help & commands. Some man pages mention reading the file `/usr/share/doc/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-faq.html` or reading http://ecryptfs.org/ too

Answer (score 0):

This was all a collection of oddities, anyway, i have got my files back, and here is how i did.

#### Getting hold of mounting/unmounting

For a bug that i think was fixed in newer versions, `ecryptfs-umount-private` did not work while i was sitting in my home folder. It was spitting the following:

```
Sessions still open, not unmounting
```

And doing nothing. Changing directory away from home, to `/` for instance, allowed me to unmount successfully.

#### Playing a bit

I created a test file in the now empty private folder, and i restarted the system. I could see the file after restart. Then i unmounted the partition, and at this point i was able to see the original README file from Ubuntu along with my files which seemed initially disappeared

#### Explanation

So, what happened? I put the files in the `Private` folder too early! Maybe i had to restart the system before. I was thinking to be putting my files in the encrypted folder, while on the other hand i was putting them in the placeholder folder which was going to be masked by the encrypted one, once mounted. The fact that the command for unmounting was failing brought more confusion, but all is well what ends well!